# Security: using CanCan to make sure user cannot see other users' profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise, cancan

I've got an app that uses Devise, CanCan and Rolify to deal with authentication and authorization.  But I don't think I'm using these gems to the full extent.  Right now the only thing in my ability class is this:

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

I found a security hole where an authenticated user is able to look at other user profiles.  I fixed it by changing some code in the user controller.

```
def show
  @user = current_user.has_role?(:admin) ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
end
```

Is this the best way to deal with this hole?  Is there a best practice or a rails convention that addresses this in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the doc](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities):

```
can :read, ModelName, :user_id => user.id
```

Comment: I saw that.  The thing is that it doesn't really change the behavior of my app.  I originally had `can :read, User, :id => user.id` instead of `can :read, all` but it didn't do anything, so I assumed it just didn't matter.  If you're confident that's my issue, then let me know if you think I just messed up the syntax or if there's some other large issue looming in the background that's causing this strange behavior.

Comment: That's the way to do, how did you test?

Comment: I tested it by restarting the server, logging in, navigating to the users profile at /users/:id and changing the id number.

Comment: do you authorize the resource in the controller?

Comment: Aha. No, I wasn't.  I oringally had `load_and_authorize_resource` in there, but had commented it out in the course of troubleshooting my error.  Thank you!